# How to make php recode_string work?

Tags: php, utf-8, latex

I'm working with apache on an Ubuntu environment.
What I'm trying to do here is to convert a LaTeX string to an UTF-8 string with PHP. recode is able to do that (LaTeX and UTF-8 are supported encodings).

It is not a native php function, so I've installed it (apt-get install php5-recode), and restarted apache. It is correctly activated.

But when I try this on a test page (encoded in UTF-8):

```
echo recode_string("LaTeX..UTF-8", "\'e");
```

I don't have any output. No error, just no output at all.

The strange thing is that the other way works:

```
echo recode_string("UTF-8..LaTeX", "é");
```

Output: \'e

Do you have any idea why recode_string is not working correctly ?